# Ruby not finding new version of OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, activesupport

Where and when does `OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER` get set?  And why isn't it getting set to the latest OpenSSL that I've just installed?

First the error(s):

```
$ gem install activesupport -v '3.2.13'
Error while executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
Unsupported digest algorithm (SHA512)
```

If I go directly into irb, I can see that Ruby is using the "old" openssl:

```
$ irb
>> require 'openssl'
=> true
>> OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha512')
RuntimeError: Unsupported digest algorithm (sha512)
>> OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER.to_s(16)
"9070cf"
```

This tells me that Ruby isn't finding the local version of OpenSSL that I just built, which should be at least 0x908000.  The relevant code:

```
# file: usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
...
alg = %w(DSS DSS1 MD2 MD4 MD5 MDC2 RIPEMD160 SHA SHA1)
if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER > 0x00908000
  alg += %w(SHA224 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512)
end
```

explains why it's not finding SHA512.

But I don't know why Ruby is using the old version of OpenSSL.  I built OpenSSL and Ruby from fresh sources using

```
SANDBOX=/Users/me/sandboxes/ruby2
PATH=$(SANDBOX)/usr/bin:$(PATH)

# Create a fresh OpenSSL from sources
(downloaded and unpacked http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz)
$ ./config --prefix=$(SANDBOX)/usr --openssldir=$(SANDBOX)/usr/openssl
$ make ; make install ; make clean
# verify openssl
$ which openssl
/Users/me/sandboxes/ruby2/usr/bin/openssl
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

# Create a fresh Ruby from sources
(download and unpack http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz)
$ ./configure --prefix=$(SANDBOX)/usr --with-open-ssl-dir=$(SANDBOX)/usr/openssl
$ make ; make intalll ; make clean
# verify ruby
$ which ruby
/Users/me/sandboxes/ruby2/usr/bin/ruby
```

But this ruby doesn't appear to find the openssl 1.0.1e that I just built.

My understanding was that the `--with-open-ssl-dir` argument to `./configure` was necessary and sufficient to tell ruby to use the new OpenSSL, but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to get Ruby to recognize the new OpenSSL that I've built?

I've tried running `ruby extconf.rb ; make ; make install` as suggested by @Gaurish (below), but that still finds the OpenSSL installed in the system, not in my project root directory.

Comment: Okay, perhaps a stupid question, but did you try `--with-openssl-dir` instead of `--with-open-ssl-dir`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TL;DR**

When OpenSSL changes, always recompile Ruby or the openssl native extension.

#### Why

Ruby compiles the OpenSSL version into the openssl native extension, even when it links to a shared OpenSSL library.  Either reinstall Ruby or recompile the openssl extension to fix it.

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
$ /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
$ strings {{redacted}/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle | grep '1.0.2'
OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
$ otool -L {{redacted}}/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle
{{redacted}}/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle:
        {{redacted}}/ruby-2.3.0/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.0)
        /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
        /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (compatibility version 14.0.0, current version 14.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

We use [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) and [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby).  Instead of `/opt/rubies`, we use `/usr/local/rubies` to avoid `sudo`. You can also `sudo ln -s /usr/local/rubies /opt/rubies` if you don't want to bother setting `RUBIES` for chruby.

```
brew install openssl && \
ruby-install ruby-2.3.0 \
  --no-install-deps \
  -- \
  --without-X11 \
  --without-tk \
  --enable-shared \
  --disable-install-doc \
  --with-openssl-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```

#### Update

There's yet another constant which **is** derived from the actual, loaded OpenSSL library.

`OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION`

Comment: I've not tried this, but your explanation is clear addresses the reasons.  So unless someone says the answer is wrong, you get the checkmark.  Thanks.

Comment: Took me way too long to figure out that this is what I needed to run to make it work `ruby-install ruby 2.3.0 -- --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3`. I hope it can help somone.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct flag to pass to `./configure` is `--with-openssl-dir`, not `--with-open-ssl-dir`.

Also, the correct value to pass to `--with-openssl-dir` in this case is `$SANDBOX/usr`, not `$SANDBOX/usr/openssl`.

Moreover, you might need to compile OpenSSL for 64-bit architecture.

This process worked for me (OS X 10.8):

```
$ export SANDBOX=/Users/me/sandboxes/ruby2
$ mkdir -p $SANDBOX/usr/bin

# Install OpenSSL 1.0.1e
$ curl -O http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.0.1e
# Copied from the Homebrew recipe for OpenSSL
$ perl ./Configure --prefix=$SANDBOX/usr --openssldir=$SANDBOX/usr/openssl zlib-dynamic shared darwin64-x86_64-cc enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
$ make depend
$ make
$ make install

# Install Ruby 2.0.0-p0
$ curl -O http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz
$ cd ruby-2.0.0-p0
$ ./configure --prefix=$SANDBOX/usr --with-openssl-dir=$SANDBOX/usr
$ make
$ make install

# Setting PATH before compiling Ruby can can cause the compilation to fail
$ export PATH=$SANDBOX/usr/bin:$PATH
$ which ruby #=>/Users/me/sandboxes/ruby2/usr/bin/ruby
$ which openssl #=> /Users/me/sandboxes/ruby2/usr/bin/openssl
$ openssl version #=> OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

$ irb
>> require "openssl"
=> true
>> OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha512")
=> #<OpenSSL::Digest: cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e>
```

You could also install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) (or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/)) and follow the [instructions for installing Ruby 2.0.0 for chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/MRI):

```
brew install openssl readline libyaml gdbm libffi
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p0
./configure --prefix=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: omg! `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-openssl-dir`

Comment: i had a view inside `./configure`, this script can not recognize this  option, so instead i used `-with-opt-dir=` this worked for me! but run in a trap again with gem then, so at the end i overruled `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` with `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:$PATH` made of a `brew install` which works fine now - server running. thanks for your tips here:)

Comment: Use [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), it's much easier.

Comment: I still get Failed to configure openssl. It will not be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, to get OpenSSL to compile and install with Ruby on Ubuntu, you need to follow these steps *after you've installed ruby*:

```
cd ruby_src_dir/ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: It appeared to work correctly (it created a new openssl.bundle), but no joy: `OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER.to_s(16)` still reports `"9070cf"`, and SHA512 isn't available.  Question: how does mkmf know where to look for libraries?  Don't I need to tell it to look in $(SANDBOX) rather than the default system libraries?

Comment: By the way, I notice I have $(SANDBOX)/usr/lib/libssl.a, but no libssl.dylib -- is that to be expected?

Comment: You're doing it the hard way.  `apt-get install libssl-dev`, compile Ruby and it will automatically build the openssl (ossl) extension automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still relevant if you have to deal with old setups:

In my case the problem lay within the OpenSSL installation.
As described [in this blog](https://tekhne.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/compiling-ruby-with-openssl-support/) you have to **make sure the shared libraries are installed** with OpenSSL :

```
$ ./config --prefix=/path/to/openssl-0.9.8g shared
$ make depend
$ make
$ make install
```

And then installed OpenSSL as usual.

For ruby I used this configure line:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/ruby-2.2.2/ --with-openssl-dir=/path/to/openssl-0.9.8g
$ make
$ make install
```

Result:

```
$ /path/to/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb
irb(main):001:0> require "openssl"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha512')
=> #<OpenSSL::Digest: cf83e13000efb8bd00042850d66d8007d620e4050b0005dc83f4a921d36ce00047d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f000931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e>
```

Comment: You should probably use an RPATH, too.

Answer (score -1):

For mac

sudo gem install openssl --install-dir vendor/bundle -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k