# How can I ensure that Ruby uses an OpenSSL not vulnerable to Heartbleed?

Tags: ruby, openssl, heartbleed-bug

Following the Heartbleed bug, [this post on ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/04/10/severe-openssl-vulnerability/) describes how to check vulnerability and upgrade.

It includes this advice:

---

To verify which version of the OpenSSL library you link to Ruby, use the following:

```
ruby -v -ropenssl -rfiddle -e 'puts Fiddle::Function.new(Fiddle.dlopen(nil)["SSLeay_version"], [Fiddle::TYPE_INT], Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP).call(0)'
```

To verify the version of OpenSSL currently installed with Ruby, use the following:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
```

---

What is the difference between these two checks, and what action is recommended if a bad version is returned from either command?

Comment: I'm guessing that one can either compile OpenSSL into the Ruby binary or let it reach out to the system library at runtime? If that's correct, how do I know which way a particular Ruby binary is using OpenSSL?

Answer (score 26):

After asking some questions [elsewhere](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/140), my current understanding is this:

- OpenSSL is never compiled along with Ruby; Ruby is simply told, at compile time, where to look for OpenSSL.
- `ruby -r rbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["configure_args"]'` should tell you where Ruby will look for various executables, including OpenSSL
- All that matters is that the copy of OpenSSL at that location is up-to-date; cd there and use `./openssl version` to find out.
- `ruby -v -ropenssl -rfiddle -e 'puts Fiddle::Function.new(Fiddle.dlopen(nil)["SSLeay_version"], [Fiddle::TYPE_INT], Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP).call(0)'` should give the same answer as running `openssl version` directly because it actually asks the copy of OpenSSL that Ruby is using to report its version number
- `OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION` may be out-of-date; it reports the version it found when it was compiled.

Comment: `OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION` to see what version ruby is running with.

Comment: I guess it might depend on Ruby packaging. At least on Debian I'm seeing different OpenSSL versions between `openssl version` and Ruby openssl

Comment: From what I can find, Ruby _does_ compile OpenSSL at compile time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222156/2917523

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to have multiple versions of OpenSSL installed on your system.  These two tests tell you which version would be linked to your Ruby if you were to do a build, and also which version is actually linked in the Ruby you are currently using.

As an example, let's say you are still using Ruby 1.9.3, and installed/compiled it last year.  It would have been linked against the version of OpenSSL you had installed at the time.  In the meantime you updated your version of OpenSSL (using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), for example), in response to the Heartbleed problem.

If you ran the first test you would get back OpenSSL 1.0.1g, the current version linked that you just upgraded.

If you ran the second test, it would reveal that your copy of Ruby is probably still linked to the older, vulnerable copy of OpenSSL.

By way of example, I'll use output from my own system (Mac OSX 10.9):

**Results on the system Ruby (2.0.0):**

```
[~] $ ruby -v -ropenssl -rfiddle -e 'puts Fiddle::Function.new(Fiddle.dlopen(nil ["SSLeay_version"], [Fiddle::TYPE_INT], Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP).call(0)'` 

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb:10    1: warning: assigned but unused variable - id
OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013


[~] $ ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
```

**Results on Ruby 2.1.1p76 (managed by rbenv, but could be RVM or other):**

```
[~] $ ruby -v -ropenssl -rfiddle -e 'puts Fiddle::Function.new(Fiddle.dlopen(nil)["SSLeay_version"], [Fiddle::TYPE_INT], Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP).call(0)'
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
[~] $ ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
```

As you can see the system ruby is linked against the `OpenSSL` included with OS X, and not yet patched by Apple.  Ruby 2.1.1 I re-built after after using `Homebrew` to upgrade my install of `OpenSSL`.

```
[~] $ brew list openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/bin/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/bin/c_rehash
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/include/openssl/ (75 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/lib/engines/ (12 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/lib/ (4 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/share/man/ (1126 files)
```

First make sure that you have the most current OpenSSL, if you are using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), just use:

`brew upgrade openssl`.

Also, make sure to remove the older versions of OpenSSL with `brew cleanup openssl`

I don't recommend patching the system Ruby, best to use a Ruby version manager, like [rbenv](http://rbenv.org) or [RVM](https://rvm.io).  After updating your SSL, remove and rebuild the versions of Ruby that you use following the normal build/install instructions for your version manager.