# Can´t install Bundler on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bundler, gitlab

I want to install Gitlab on my new Raspberry Pi 2 (with Raspbian).

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/6-5-stable/doc/install/installation.md

Under "2) Ruby" it says:

*Install the Bundler Gem:*

```
sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

When I try to run this, it just says:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there any chance, somebody knows what went wrong here - and how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129355/ruby-2-0-rails-gem-install-error-cannot-load-such-file-openssl

Comment: I tried to install OpenSSL and then recompile ruby, but it did not work. OpenSSL Version 1.0.1e (11 Feb 2013) installed. Ruby Version: 2.0.0.p353 (2013-11-22). Anything else I can try? Maybe try the same on normal Linux and not Raspbian? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Possibly running some of the commands from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23161192/254973)? I'm thinking that Ruby isn't finding OpenSSL for some reason.