# NotImplementedError (authenticated?() function is unimplemented on this machine

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, osx-elcapitan

I've got the following code:

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CFB").authenticated?
```

No matter the algorithm I pass in (any of the types returned from OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers) I get the followin exception:

```
NotImplementedError (authenticated?() function is unimplemented on this machine
```

Setup:

OS X (El Capitan) 10.11.3

ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]

Any help resolving this would be appreciated. I have confirmed on *nix and non-El-Capitan machines that this works.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Ruby 2.0? It looks like `OpenSSL::Cipher#authenticated?` was added in Ruby 2.0. What do you get for `RUBY_VERSION`?

Comment: Yes: ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.0.0"

Comment: What version of OpenSSL? (`OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION`) You may need to upgrade your OpenSSL.

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8zc 19 Mar 2015

Comment: Yeah, you should try upgrading OpenSSL. The answer here describes how you can do it with Homebrew: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993541/how-can-i-ensure-that-ruby-uses-an-openssl-not-vulnerable-to-heartbleed